# Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging package could not be installed

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging, nuget-package

I am trying to install xamarin.firebase.messaging package in xamarin android project in visual studio for push notifications but it is giving this error.

```
Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 24.2.1'. You are 
trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any assembly 
references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more 
information, contact the package author.
```

[image: This is my application properties:]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the latest Android version for compilation

Android 8.1 (Oreo)

Also I recommend you to update your Xamarin.Forms to latest stable version

Comment: In compilation drop down, Oreo isn't an option.

Comment: You need to go to tools-> Android-> Android SDK Manager and check the SDK and click apply changes.. The SDK size is more.. Also see my updated answer